# Artillery guns near Triglav?

Tags: world-war-two, military, world-war-one

My friends and I were climbing near Triglav (Slovinia) last weekend, and there was some memorial for people who died pulling guns up the mountain. Now I don't remember which era that was, but I am asuming it was WW2. My question is how important could those guns really have been? Which type of guns were these, and how did they get them up? Generally anything about this as I could not find anything about it. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Triglav, Slovenia,](https://www.dolina-soce.com/en/valley_of_discoveries/a_century_after_the_first_world_war/) was a part of the former Yugoslavia. During World War I, it was part of the Austro-Hungarian Empire, which fought against Italy (one of the "Allies"), among others. There was fighting around there in World War II as well, but by Yugoslav guerrillas that didn't have artillery.

It was a critical point on the Italian and Austrian borders near where it intersects the borders with Switzerland. It was a mountainous area, that connected the plains containing Austria's Vienna and Italy's Venice. The mountains protected both of these key cities from the enemy, unless said enemy dominated the whole plateau.

Essentially the whole of the Austro-Italian fighting took place in this general area, between 1915-1917. The Germans and Austrians got the better of the Italians at the battle of [Capretto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Caporetto),  threatening Venice, and nearly knocking Italy out of the war. The Italians hoped that it would be the other way, with an advance on Vienna.

[Mountain artillery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mountain_artillery) is a special "breed." It has to be heavy enough to do the job, but light enough to carry up mountains, which is to say that it can be "disaasembled," and then reassembled at the top. Even so, carrying the pieces up mountains is no easy task. The guns on Triglav were likely 65 and 70 caliber Italian and Austrian artillery of World War I vintage.

Answer (score 4):

I think that was on the Isonzo Front during the *First*, rather than the Second World War.

There were actually 12 [Battles of the Isonzo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battles_of_the_Isonzo) between the armies of the Austro-Hungarian Empire and the Italian army. These were fought between May 1915 and October 1917, and were every bit as brutal as those fought on the Western Front.

[Both sides used artillery](https://encyclopedia.1914-1918-online.net/article/isonzo_battles_of) in these battles. In fact, artillery was said to have been decisive in the [Seventh Battle of the Isonzo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seventh_Battle_of_the_Isonzo). In the early stages it was mostly light, 75mm guns, but medium and heavy guns began to be introduced to the theatre from 1916. Some images in this [picture gallery](http://www.historyofwar.org/pictures_isonzo_trentino.html) show artillery on these fronts. A couple of the pictures show artillery pieces being moved - pulled by horses and manpower.